# SQL Cambiar formato de fecha a texto

Tags: sql, sql-server

necesito de su ayuda para cambiar el formato de un campo fecha para una consulta select en SQL (formato original del campo **1947-08-07 00:00:00.000**)  a un formato de **texto simple algo así 19470807000000000**

utilizando lo comandos `CONVERT  (CHAR (50),FechaNacimiento, 112) AS fecha` obtengo **19470807** como fecha bien, pero la hora `CONVERT  (CHAR (50),FechaNacimiento, 114) AS hora` obtengo **00:00:00:000**, si utilizo el `CAST  (RIGHT (FechaNacimiento, 7) AS CHAR (50)) AS HORA` obtengo **12:00AM**,
utilizando `CAST (FechaNacimiento AS varchar ) AS fecha_hora` obtengo **Aug  7 1947 12:00AM**

y necesito obtener el texto simple de la hora **000000000**  **000000** o en su defecto de todo el campo **19470807000000000**

Como verna en los ejemplos utilizando el CONVERT  y el  CAST  no me son muy útiles para la conversion que necesito.

alguien conocerá algún otro método en SQL

Nota: el Objetivo es crear una vista alterando los formatos de fecha y hora originales de la tabla en un texto simple.

Comment: pero ya lo tenes resuelto! si concatenas el primer convert con el segundo convert, pero y haces un replace de texto donde cambies : por nada, no es lo que queres????

Comment: No porque no logro tener la hora en el sistente formato   000000000 sin los puntos de separación **:**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que no hay ninguna función que realice la conversión directamente al formato que a ti te interesa, se me ocurre las siguientes alternativas:

Puedes hacerlo con [`convert()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), si lo combinas con [`replace()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) para *eliminar* algunos caracteres que no quieres ver, por ejemplo, el formato 126 nos devolverá la cadena con formato ISO8601, es decir `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.fff` (el formato siempre obvia los milisegundos si estos son 0). Entonces, en esta cadena debemos *salir* de los `'-'`, `':'` y la `'T'`:

```
select replace(replace(replace(convert(varchar, fecha, 127), '-', ''), ':', ''), 'T', '') FechaStr
  from Tabla
```

Dará el formato que quieres, en mis pruebas, por ejemplo:

```
FechaStr
--------------------
20200101173245
20210318000000
20210731000000

(3 rows affected)
```

Una manera de simplificar la escritura de la consulta final (sobre todo si son muchas) es *encapsular* la conversión dentro de una función, por ejemplo:

```
create function FechaToStr(@fecha datetime) returns varchar(20)
as 
begin
  return replace(replace(replace(convert(varchar, @fecha, 126), '-', ''), ':', ''), 'T', '')
end;
go
```

Te permitiría luego obtener los datos con una consulta como esta:

```
select dbo.FechaToStr(fecha) FechaStr
  from MiTabla;
```

(Estoy asumiendo que tu esquema por default es `dbo`)

Comment: Gracia, funciono perfecto, a hora le puedo agregar las funciones LEFT, RIGHT y SUBSTRING

`select 
RIGHT((replace(replace(replace(convert(varchar, Fecha_campo, 127), '-', ''), ':', ''), 'T', '')),6)
from Tabla`

La manera de simplificar la escritura de la consulta final esta genial . 
gracias ..